# Swift 2 FirebaseTableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to firebase and swift programming. I am trying to populate a tableview with data from firebase. I keep getting (expected declaration) error at self.dataSource Line. Any help will be gladly appreciated, thanks in advance...

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

import FirebaseUI

class ChurchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items = [NSDictionary]()

    let firebaseRef = Firebase(url:"https://........com/")
    let dataSource: FirebaseTableViewDataSource! = nil

    self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: self.firebase, cellReuseIdentifier: "Cell", view: self.tableView)

    self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
    let snap = items[indexPath.row]
    //obj as! FDataSnapshot

    // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
    cell.textLabel?.text = snap["ChurchName"] as String
    }

    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
```

I got this from the firebase document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
let dataSource...
```

should be

```
var dataSource...
```

let is used for something that won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible things.

1) ref in self.dataSource = should be firebaseRef, not self.firebase.

2) General suggestion: I think you may want to use a version of FirebaseTableViewDataSource that contains the constructor that defines cellClass so you can use a custom cell, otherwise it returns UITableViewCell (someone check me on that)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, but I tried what you suggested and the error  is still there.